# my List of comparison operators in php returns '1' when I use keyword echo why

Tags: php

I'm begenning at PHP , I was poking around my code and learning about List of comparison operators , however I'll try out to put echo before my comparasion operators and I've received this result : 1 then I though the reason is comparasion true equal to 1, else equal to 0 , in this moment seemed me somethig kinda python, yet I just got the 1 . why not 0 as result ?

Is attached my question

[image: my question help please]

Comment: Please **never** post code as image. Format your question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing a boolean value. The value is converted to a string where 1 represents true and a blank string represents false.

From the manual:

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

You could use the ternary operator to output the string true or false where appropriate. Example:

```
echo (10 >= 12) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 1):

when print boolean value in php it will print 1 if `TRUE` and "" if `FALSE`.

if you want to print 0 if `FALSE` then you can convert into `int`.

in your case you can use like this

```
$bool = 10 >= 12;
echo (int)$bool;
```

it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo 10>=9 // print 1 as it is true
echo 11>3 // print 1
echo 11 == 11 // print 1
echo 10>=12 // print nothing because it is false
```

This happening becuase a boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).